# Drupal 7: missing page parts

Tags: drupal

We have a working Drupal 7 production site developed by an outside vendor. Now I want a local development version on my office computer (Windows, I'm afraid).  I set up a WAMP stack, git cloned the working production site to my computer, and copied the database.  I also copied from the production site /sites/default/settings.php and /sites/default//files .  The result partially works.

The one problem that may not need site-specific details is that no menu works.  Every place a menu is supposed to appear, Drupal generates the containers for the top level links, but these containers are empty.  Examples include the Megamenu and the black bar at the top you get on login.  /admin/structure/menu lists our various menus, but the links under "Operations" ("list links", "edit menu", and "add menu" do not appear. /admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu (for example) shows the menu structure with the move-me icons but without any menu names or operations links. /admin/structure/menu/item/539/edit (for example) shows all the proper information.

Note that it is not only menus that are not working.  Other stuff is missing.  Anything that gets shoveled into a template dynamically rather than specified by editing the content of some page is missing.  What is working?  Anything you enter into any field when creating/editing a Basic Page (or other page type) is working.  So, for example, news stories show up fine (we have a news page type), but a container that is supposed to show a news story title in an  tag is empty.

I must have missed something in trying to clone the production site because production works.  But I don't know what.  Maybe if I had an idea as to what could cause the problems above, it could give me a place to start looking.  Any ideas what might cause such a problems, especially something that might be missed in a git and db clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem automagically fixed itself without any changes on my part.

I was asked if I had cleared the cache.  I had turned caching off on production before dumping the database (and then turned it back on) so there would be no cache to clear on the development site.  However, I was told that I also needed to clear the session data.  So I'm guessing that a session garbage collection run fixed the problem.

Added:

Actually, I misunderstood part of what I was told.  Apparently, there are parts of Drupal's cache you can't turn off.  So I had been mistaken in thinking that there was no cache to clear.